# Merging multiple pandas columns together

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the following data frame:

| 2020 | 2021 | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | 5 | NaN |
| 12 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | 15 |

to the following:

| Merged |
| --- |
| 10 |
| 5 |
| 12 |
| 15 |

Some considerations:

- There can be multiple columns (more than the three shown 2020, 2021,
  2022)
- Only 1 column will ever have a value, the rest have NaNs

What is a clean efficient way to do this type of column merge?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.stack()`?

Comment: `df['Merged'] = df.sum(1)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `fillna()` and play around it:

so here you will forward fill your values by setting `method = 'ffill'` and then picking up the last column

```
output = (df.fillna(method='ffill',downcast='infer',axis=1)
            .iloc[:,-1].to_frame(name='merged'))
```

OR

in the opposite way you can use backword fill by setting `method = 'bfill'` and then picking up the first column:

```
output = (df.fillna(method='bfill',downcast='infer',axis=1)
            .iloc[:,0].to_frame(name='merged'))
```

**Note:** Also you can use `df.sum(axis=1)` but let's say you won't have values in exactly 1 column then it won't work(it will sum up those values) and additionally To keep the record let's say which value is belong to which year you can use:

```
output = (df.melt(var_name="Year",value_name="Merged")
            .dropna(subset=["Merged"]).astype({"Merged":"int"}))
```